# How to reduce amount of if conditions on Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, coding-style

I have a function in Python which looks like this:

```py
def ldm_discount(ldm):
  if ldm <= 1:
    return 0.3
  if ldm <=2:
    return 0.38
  if ldm <=3:
    return 0.45
  if ldm <=4:
    return 0.51
  if ldm <=5:
    return 0.57
  if ldm <=6:
    return 0.63
  if ldm <=7:
    return 0.69
  if ldm <=8:
    return 0.75
  if ldm <=9:
    return 0.80
  if ldm <=10:
    return 0.85
  else:
    return 1
```

It seems to me there might be a better way. How can I reduce the amount of if statements?

**UPDATE:** Btw I can't use imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def ldm_discount(ldm):
    ldm = round(ldm)
    ldm_discount={1:0.3,2:0.38}
    discount = ldm_discount.get(ldm,None)
    return discount
```

Comment: Seems to me this is even better solution. Thank you! But what if ```ldm > 10```?

Comment: I dont think there will be any issue  regardless of the ldm value, just make sure your dictionary has the correct mapping.

Comment: So I have to set: ```ldm_discount.get(ldm,1)```. right?

Comment: No don't do that, unless if you want the default discount value to be 1, I think 0 will be better, because that will mean if there is no match for the ldm in the dictionary, there is no discount for such ldm value and 0 will be returned.

Answer (score 3):

Assign all outputs in a list, iterate over a list and match ldm with list indices.

```
vals = [0.3,0.38,0.45,0.51,0.57,0.63,0.69,0.75,0.80,0.85]
def ldm_discount(ldm):
    for i in range(1,len(vals)+1):
        if ldm <= i:
            return vals[i-1]
    return 1
```

```
ldm_discount(2)
>> 0.38
```

```
ldm_discount(5)
>> 0.57
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from math import ceil

def ldm_discount(ldm):
  index = ceil(ldm)
  values = [0.3, 0.38, 0.45, .......]
  if ldm <= 10:
    return values[index - 1]
  else:
    return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single `if` statement by finding out the correct index directly:

```
import math
def ldm_discount(ldm):
    discounts = [0.3, 0.38, 0.45, 0.51, 0.57, 0.63, 0.69, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85]
    return discounts[math.ceil(ldm) - 1] if ldm <= 10 else 1
```

Notice that you must make sure `ldm` is not negative or zero, otherwise it will do a negative indexing or an `IndexError`(out of range).

Or you can slightly change the condition:

```
import math
def ldm_discount(ldm):
    discounts = [0.3, 0.38, 0.45, 0.51, 0.57, 0.63, 0.69, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85]
    return discounts[math.ceil(ldm) - 1] if 0 < ldm <= 10 else 0 if ldm == 0 else 1
```

### Edit (no imports)

`math` is part of the built-in python modules, but in case you can't use any kind of import, you can do your own `ceil`.

```
discounts = [0.3, 0.38, 0.45, 0.51, 0.57, 0.63, 0.69, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85]
def ldm_discount(ldm): 
    casted = int(ldm)
    return discounts[casted - 1 if ldm == casted else casted] if 0 < ldm <= len(discounts) else 0 if ldm == 0 else 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.10 introduces the "match" statement, which in other languages is usually known as a "switch" statement. See [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/)

That said, as you mentioned, there's probably a nicer way to do what you're currently doing.

You could for example use a dictionary and loop through it:

```
values = {
 1: 0.3,
 2: 0.38,
 ...
}

for threshold in values.keys():
 if ldm <= threshold:
  return values
```